# Suddenly added some large files to git VCS

Tags: git

I've suddenly added some large files to GIT VCS repository.

I and committed them.
And I don't know how to remove them.

I tried searching and tried some ways but I couldn't find a way to find them and remove them.

I am using GIT CLI.

thank you for your help.

Edit:
I'm using android studio with grade. some *.pid files added to project that committed in project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before
try these commands:
first find large files with this command:

`git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | awk '/^blob/ {print substr($0,6)}' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2`

and them try to remove them with this command.

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/large/file' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

this command will remove a alrge file from all your repository means all commits and tags and branches.

Comment: Yeah it worked. there are some large files like *.pid what are they and how created? I am using android studio.

Comment: I think those are created by Java and Gradle it might be closed suddenly that could cause to dump memory and create those files. try to add `*.pid` in your `.gitignore` file to avoid add them again to the repository.